# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila de un DataFrame dado lista con las condiciones?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo una pequeña pregunta que desarrollare en el siguiente ejemplo. Tengo el DataFrame de la muestra y tengo la lista (ex = ['ACC','ACB','ACE]), la idea es eliminar del DataFrame las filas que en la columna código no contengan algún elemento de la lista anterior.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [ACC, "Elemento1","125"], 
                    [BWW, "Elemento2","150"],
                    [ACE, "Elemento3","-220"],
                    [ACB, "Elemento4","-275"],
                    [BWE, "Elemento5","500"]]),
                   columns=['Código', 'Columna','Columna3'])
```

Y quiero obtener:

````
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
                    [ACC, "Elemento1","125"], 
                    [ACE, "Elemento3","-220"],
                    [ACB, "Elemento4","-275"],
                    columns=['Código', 'Columna','Columna3'])``` 

Trate con el siguiente comando y no me funciono correctamente.
   
for k in ex: 
    df.drop(df[df['Código']!=k].index, inplace=True)
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo una lista de valores posibles, lo más sencillo es usar [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) para seleccionar las filas deseadas:

```
df.loc[df.Código.isin(ex), ]
```

---

Con lo cual generas un nuevo `dataframe` con las condiciones buscadas.

Comment: No me funciono, aunque si es por el lado de isin pero no me borra lo que necesito.

Comment: Que raro, por que lo probé antes y me parece que es lo que esperas: https://replit.com/@pmoracho/como-eliminar-una-fila-de-un-dataframe-dado-lista-con-las-co

Comment: Tenia un error pero ya lo arregle y efectivamente esa linea de código que me enviaste funciona. Muchas gracias.